# Please help solving some Boolean Algebra problems

Tags: boolean-algebra

I want to know how these problems are solved. Thank you very much.

i) x·y + y·z + x'·z = x.y + x'·z
ii) (x + y)·(x' + z) = x·z + x'·y

Comment: I don't see a problem. Where have you got stuck?

Comment: @user251257 I'm unable to find proper operations to prove these identities. That's why I really need some help...thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one,

$$\begin{align*}
xy+yz+x'z&=xy+(x+x')yz+x'z\\
&=xy+xyz+x'yz+x'z\\
&=xy(1+z)+x'z(1+y)\;;
\end{align*}$$

can you finish it from there?

For the second,

$$\begin{align*}
(x+y)(x'+z)&=(x+y)x'+(x+y)z\\
&=xx'+yx'+xz+yz\\
&=x'y+xz+yz\;;
\end{align*}$$

now use the first one after renaming some of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Well for i) you don't need yz cos xy+x'z <=yz and for ii) when you multiply it you will get similar to i)